# Spark Scala - dataset[array[string]] having records -convert to records starting from new line

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `Dataset[Array[String]]` having string like

```
12345, 2341, a465c2a, p, 2015-06-10, 2015-02-23, 2015-02-23, 2, "", 1, 98941, 1, ., 17, 21, 1, "", 67890, 4313, a465c2a, p, 2015-06-10, 2015-02-23, 2015-02-23, 2, 7391, 1, 98941, 1, ., 17, 21, 1, 01
```

In this string starting from zero a record end at 16 position 17th index is the starting of new record.
how to save it as a text file in Spark such that every new record starts at a new line.
I know a dataset can be saved as a textFile like write.text

Comment: can you please be more specific regarding "end at 16 position 17th index is the starting of new record" as i can see there are spaces before each record so saying index is creating confusion

Comment: spaces are not to be considered..It is comma seperated. 16 index is last index of the record and 17th index of the string is first column of the next record and so on

Comment: so if go with above sample then 67890 is the last field of the first column and 4313 is first field for the second column , if in correct plz correct me

Comment: 67890 is the first field of 2nd record and 4313 is the second field of the second record likewise 12345 is the first field of first record and 2341 is the second field of the first record. a record has 16 fields starting from zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `sliding` function on your `Array[String]` and append `"\n"` at the end of the `String` as you already know the end index of the line.

```
//your original Dataset
val data: Dataset[Array[String]] = sqlContext.createDataset(Seq(Array("12345", "2341", "a465c2a",
  "p", "2015-06-10", "2015-02-23", "2015-02-23", "2", " ", "1",
  "98941", "1", ".", "17", "21", "1", "67890", "4313", "a465c2a",
  "p", "2015-06-10", "2015-02-23", "2015-02-23", "2", "7391",
  "1", "98941", "1", ".", "17", "21", "1", "01")))

//apply sliding function to the Array and append \n
val result: RDD[String] = data.rdd.map(_.sliding(17, 17).map(_.mkString(",") + "\n").mkString(""))

//to display the output  
result.foreach(print(_))

//output
//12345,2341,a465c2a,p,2015-06-10,2015-02-23,2015-02-23,2, ,1,98941,1,.,17,21,1,67890
//4313,a465c2a,p,2015-06-10,2015-02-23,2015-02-23,2,7391,1,98941,1,.,17,21,1,01

//to save the result to file
result.saveAsTextFile("PATH_TO_SAVE_FILE")
```